# How should this multi-inheritance situation be handled?

Tags: django, database-design

## The problem

I have the "base model" `Listing` which is responsible for storing basic data for every possible item we will be posting to our site. A `Listing` has the most basic details, while inherited models like `Equipment` or `Material` should extend it with required things like `price`.

For example, we have a `Listing` we'd like to extend with `Equipment` specific fields.

## My current attempt at solving it

I have the following models:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # listing stuff

class AbstractListingGood(models.Model):
    price = MoneyField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD', null=True, blank=True)
    # other listing goods details

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Equipment(AbstractListingGood, Listing):
    year = models.PositiveIntegerField(max_length=4, null=True, blank=True)
    make = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    # equipment details

class Material(AbstractListingGood, Listing):
    hazardous = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
```

And here's how I'm trying to create the base `Listing` object and extend it to have `Equipment` fields:

```
extended_obj = Material(listing_ptr_id=obj.pk)
extended_obj.price = form.cleaned_data['price']
extended_obj.quantity = int(form.cleaned_data['quantity'])

for (key, value) in obj.__dict__.items():
    setattr(extended_obj, key, value)

extended_obj.save()
```

## The problem with my solution

I used to just have all of the fields present in `Listing` like `price`, `year`, `make`, etc. but they were taking up space and made the `Listing` model kind of ugly. We wanted to split it off into separate more lightweight and extensible models.

Now I have all kinds of problems trying to find `Listing.material.price` versus `Listing.equipment.price` and lots of mis-understanding of what's happening in the backend.

What should I do!? How should I solve this problem? Is it a huge no-no to have a Model with ~15-20 potentially empty fields that are unused?

Comment: Does every `Listing` has a price, year, make, etc? If yes the proper way is to have them on `Listing`.

Comment: The way I see it you have 2 options. Create an abstract class with all the common fields and inherit that.

Second option would be to create a Listing model and the Materials and Equipment models should have a foreign key to it. In those 2 models you can store data specific to those types of listings.

Comment: rantanplan Nope not all of them!

@GabrielSamfira Isn't that the same as the way I have it basically? Just under the hood it's creating the one-to-one?